# Embed PNG Encoded in System.Net.Mail HTML Message

Tags: html, asp.net

Let's assume that I'm already sending email messages and all that is working OK. I'm trying to embed a Base64 img in the HTML for a system.net.mail message inline and it's not working. It shows everything and the source on the email has the image embedded but it's not showing.

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>Ralph Wiggums</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...deleted for size sake...ErkJggg=="></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to play games with `<`/`>`. Just be sure to indent the code so that it shows up as code.

Comment: What's the mail client? For example, Outlook has terrible HTML support which hasn't been updated since IE5.5, and doesn't support `data:` URIs.